# ImportError: No module named cloud in AppEngine, python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-app-engine-python

i have a problem when i try to execute my script.py througth appengine just with the library 
"from google.cloud import bigquery", i try some solutions but i have not had a success way, i show you the scripts which i use to execute this script.

This is my script:

```
import json
import datetime
import webapp2
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')

filename = "example.json"

def date_format(time):
        if time.find(".") != -1:
            time = time[:time.find(".")]
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(time,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        return date.strftime("%Y%m%d")


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        with open(filename) as file:
            array = []
            jsonData = json.load(file)
            d = str(date_format(jsonData['e']))
            self.response.write('Hello AppEngine from script! :: '+d)

            client = bigquery.Client()

            QUERY = (           
                    'SELECT field FROM `table` WHERE date='+d+' LIMIT 10'
                    )
            query_job = client.query(QUERY)
            rows = query_job.result()
            for row in rows:
                print(row.field)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

This is my app.yaml:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

This is my requirements.txt:

```
google-api-python-client
google-cloud
```

I have a lib directory with the bigquery library: google_cloud_bigquery-1.24.0.dist-info.
and others libraries with google_cloud

I dont know if my code is correct, because i have saw some solutions but anything helpme to run script with appengine.

i hope you can help me please.

**This is the script with python 3**

```
import google.cloud.bigquery as bigquery
# [START gae_python37_app]
from flask import Flask
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')


# If `entrypoint` is not defined in app.yaml, App Engine will look for an app
# called `app` in `main.py`.
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
    client = bigquery.Client()
    QUERY = (           
            'SELECT ev FROM `table` WHERE f="20200201" LIMIT 10'
            )
    query_job = client.query(QUERY)
    rows = query_job.result()
    for row in rows:
        return row.ev


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This is used when running locally only. When deploying to Google App
    # Engine, a webserver process such as Gunicorn will serve the app. This
    # can be configured by adding an `entrypoint` to app.yaml.
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
# [END gae_python37_app]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using App Engine Standard's Python 2.7 runtime. This runtime does not allow you to specify dependencies with a `requirements.txt` file.

Instead, you should follow this guide to vendor any dependencies like `google-cloud-bigquery` along with your application: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27

You may need to remove any existing `lib` directory entirely and start again.

Also, note that the [`google-cloud`](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud/) package is deprecated, you should not use it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when i remove and install the google-cloud library, after appear other error... ImportError: No module named concurrent.futures, i searched this error to try resolve it with a pip install futures, but wasn't possible, the error still appear in appengine, i tried to run this script with python 3, but now appear ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google', i tried with pip3 install google, but the error still appear.

Comment: I see now that you're using App Engine Standard's Python 2.7 runtime. This runtime does not allow you to specify dependencies with a `requirements.txt` file, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27. I've updated my answer accordingly.